# Plotting single points and their range

Tags: r, plot, points

I am trying to plot some data points from a matrix complete with their standard deviation, but I am having troubles in plotting the latter.

My tools are:

1. a matrix with the data points to plot at a x coordinate within a properly xlim-defined x-axis;
2. a vector of as many y arbitrary coordinates for the plotting height, just not making them overlap;
3. a vector of lengths of the standard deviation lines, to be displayed horizontally around the data points.

Yeah, eventually it'll look like a flying saucer invasion.

I can easily plot the points at the given height, one by one - it is the way I want to do it.

Trouble comes in adding the standard deviation horizontal lines for each point.

Has someone an idea on how to do it?

```
x<-matrix(c(1:4,NA,NA,10:16), nrow=4, ncol=4)
y<-seq(0.001,0.006, 0.001)
std.dev<-c(runif(7, 0.1, 0.5), NA, NA, runif(7, 0.1, 0.5))

plot(0,0, xlim=c(min = 0, max(x), na.rm=T)+0.001), ylim = c(0,0.016), type = "n", xlab = "My x", yaxt = "n", ylab ="")

points(x = x[1,2], y = y[1], pch = 21, bg = "red", col = "red")
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with `base R` it is amazing to find out that R does not provide a "built-in" support for error bars. You may want to consult doing this with other packages.

With `base R` the work-around is to use the `arrow()` function and setting the "arrow head angle" to 90 degrees.

Note: I had to change your given data definition as it threw errors. Also have a look at this part of your code.

I plot the error bars in vertical mode. You can easily adapt this for horizontal bars. I did this for presentation reasons to avoid overlapping error bars.
Using your full data will make it easier to deconflict the bars.

```
x<-matrix(c(1:7,NA,NA,10:16), nrow=4, ncol=4)      # adapted to ensure same length
y<-seq(0.001,0.016, 0.001)                         # adapted to ensure same length
std.dev<-c(runif(7, 0.1, 0.5), NA, NA, runif(7, 0.1, 0.5))

plot(0,0
    , xlim=  c(min = 0, max(x, na.rm=T))           # had to fix xlim definition
    , ylim = c(-1,1)                               # changed to show give std.dev
    , type = "n", xlab = "My x", yaxt = "n", ylab ="")

points(x = x, y = y, pch = 21, bg = "red", col = "red")  # set x and y to show all

# --------------- add arrows with "flat head --------------------------
arrows( x0 = x, , x1 = x
       ,y0 = y-std.dev, y1 = y+std.dev   # center deviation on data point
       , code=3, angle=90      # set the angle for the head to emulate error bar
       , length=0.1)
```

This yields:

[image]